# TextView From Response

Tags: java, android, json

Im trying to get Geolocation JSON data with URL from this API http://ip-api.com/json/?fields=query,country,city and show IP Address, City, Country to my TextView layout

Response:

```
{"city":"Bandung","country":"Indonesia","query":"127.0.0.1"}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button start;
    TextView textView;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    public static TextView data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lokasi);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLok);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           @Override
           public void onClick(View ){

               JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://ip-api.com/json/?fields=query,country,city",
                       new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                               JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                               String city = jsonObject.getString("city");
                               String country= jsonObject.getString("country");
                               String ip = jsonObject.getString("query");

                           }
                       },

                       new Response.ErrorListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Log.e("VOLLEY","ERROR");
                           }
                       }


               )
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is JavaScript involved?

Comment: Yes, javascript involved

Comment: @YogaAprilliansyahN *`Yes, javascript involved`*  where is the code of `javascript`?,  there is no single line of code in your question written in `javascript`

Comment: you can take a response from http call and create one model to parse the data and set to textview

Comment: @NilleshRathod sorry, i mean Java Languange

Comment: @Vishalkumarsinghvi where i can put the code?

Comment: Are you getting the JSON that you posted? Or what is the main issue here? Where did you get stucked?

Comment: @BrankVictoria i want to show the output json into my TextView layout android studio

Comment: Yes, but I don't see in your code where do you have your JSON output...

Comment: @BrankVictoria That's why, i dont know how to make output json code for show in TextView

Comment: I want to show JSON Output like this http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ISH-3YqdTxM/Vlw6y382KfI/AAAAAAAAA7A/DGQhT0-zM2A/s1600/Screenshot_2015-11-30-16-51-00.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your response (that you get from the api) into a JSONObject.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(myResponse);
```

After that you can parse the jsonObject.

```
String city = jsonObject.getString("city");
String country= jsonObject.getString("country");
String ip = jsonObject.getString("query");
```

Then just put the strings into your text view.

UPDATE:

Just change the onResponse to this.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
       String city = response.getString("city");
       String country= response.getString("country");
       String ip = response.getString("query");
}
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/l9w9jn error: cannot find symbol method JSONObject(JSONObject)

Comment: Add this into your gradle dependenncies. Implementation 'org.json:json:20180813'

Comment: Actually seeing your screenshot you forgot to add "new" keyword.

Comment: Is the response you get a string? The response has to be a string. Also surround the block where you use JSONObject with try catch for a JSONException.

Comment: i have already updated my question, please correct my source code

Comment: Thanks, i completed my project.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Make One POJO for your Response like Example.java

```
    public class Example {

    @SerializedName("city")
    @Expose
    private String city;
    @SerializedName("country")
    @Expose
    private String country;
    @SerializedName("query")
    @Expose
    private String query;

    public String getCity() {
    return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
    return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
    }

    public String getQuery() {
    return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
    this.query = query;
    }

    }
```

Step 2. parse a string response

```
    Example ex = gson.fromJson(json, BoxSearch.class);
```

Step 3. Now get value from POJO

```
    String city = ex.getCity();
    String country= ex.getQuery();
    String ip = ex.getCountry();
```

Step 4. Set value in Textview

```
    txtCity.setText(city);
    txtCountry.setText(country);
    txtIp .setText(ip);
```